# What is the difference between HAC and PCSE?

Tags: references, panel-data, heteroscedasticity, fixed-effects-model, gretl

I have data consist of 88 companies in 5 year (440 observations) and used 3 independent variables with 3 control variables (total 6 variables). I have already test the best model for my data and the best model is Fixed Effect Model. But my data is suffered from heteroscedasticity and I want to fix it. In gretl, there is a checkbox "robust standard error" and there is 2 options; Arellano (HAC) and PCSE.

1. Which one is the best to fix my heteroscedasticity problem?
2. Is there any book or guidance or journal that explain about it?
3. Which one is the closest one to robust standard error by White?
4. Is there any other solutions in gretl that can help to fix heteroscedasticity problem in fixed effect model?

Answer (score 1):

The Gretl User Guide that comes with the program has an explanation in section 19.4 (at the time of writing), "Special issues with panel data".
I'm quoting some excerpts:

"Gretl currently offers two robust covariance matrix estimators specifically for panel data. These are available for models estimated via fixed effects, random effects, pooled OLS, and pooled two-stage least squares. The default robust estimator is that suggested by Arellano (2003), which is
HAC provided the panel is of the “large n, small T ” variety (that is, many units are observed in relatively few periods)." ...

"In cases where autocorrelation is not an issue the estimator proposed by Beck and Katz (1995) and discussed by Greene (2003, chapter 13) may be appropriate. This estimator, which takes into account contemporaneous correlation across the units and heteroskedasticity by unit, is ... 
 Beck and Katz call the associated standard errors “Panel-Corrected Standard Errors” (PCSE). " ...

You seem to have a small-T panel (5 years as you say), so the Arellano option would be possible. If you believe or know that you do not have remaining autocorrelation you could use PCSE instead, allowing for some cross unit correlation. It depends on what you are ready to assume for your case.